# vhost changes on linux not showing

Tags: apache, centos, vhosts

Here is the situation.

I was making a change in the URL in the vhost file to a new URL.

Then, I restarted the server, but somehow the new URL is not working but the old URL is.

The linux that I'm running is Centos.

Here is the old vhost file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.com
      ServerAlias www.test.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/test

      HostnameLookups Off
      UseCanonicalName Off
      ServerSignature Off

      <Directory "var/www/test">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
       </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

Here is the new vhost file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test-new.com
      ServerAlias www.test-new.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/test

      HostnameLookups Off
      UseCanonicalName Off
      ServerSignature Off

      <Directory "var/www/test">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
       </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

Is there a step that I'm missing to make sure the changes are in effect?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: It's not clear what "URL is not showing" or "making a change in the URL" means.

Comment: Which kind of server software are you using? Please post your question with some sample vhost configs.

Comment: I posted the sample vhost files.

Comment: Sorry if it looks like a stupid question, but did you "stop" then "start" or just "restart" ?